# Command line auto complete tab key not work in terminal for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am runing Ubuntu 13.10. When I remote login through remote desktop and using the terminal, I can not use the tab key to auto complete the command for item such as file/directory. The remote window manager is xfce, and the termial shell is bash.

If I access the same box using SSH, I can use tab key to auto complete.

What is the key for auto complete command for the terminal emulator in xfce window? The regular tab key does not work.

Answer (score 31):

I had this problem using XFCE and TigerVNC: pressing tab just switched between the terminals I had open. It was solved by following the directions given in the link @Jonas provided: http://how-to.cc/fix-bash-command-line-completion. I will copy a few pieces in here in case the link should ever be broken.

**Step 1:**

Make sure that your `.bashrc` file contains something like

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

so that a file containing bash completion info is actually sourced. In my case, `/etc/bash_completion` pointed to `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` which contained the stuff to set up. For reference, the end of my `.bashrc` looked like this:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

**Step 2:**

Disable the behaviour of tab changing windows. This is done in the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` by changing the line

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"/>
```

to

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="empty"/>
```

**Step 3:**

Reboot or restart your VNC server (XFCE).

Answer (score 29):

Try this,

1. Open the `Xfce Application Menu > Settings > Window Manager`
2. Click on the `Keyboard` Tab
3. Clear the `Switch window for same application setting`

Refer [here](https://www.starnet.com/xwin32kb/tab-key-not-working-when-using-xfce-desktop/).

Comment: This is the simplest thing that solved the problem. Should be the accepted answer. The problem is not an XFCE bug, simply a poorly chosen default keyboard shortcut for a window manager function that can easily be remapped so a press on Tab is not captures by the window manager.

Comment: Thank you for finding this.

Comment: You save my day

Answer (score 13):

The XFCE Terminal has kidnapped the tab key for a feature of it's own, tab/windows switching.
Instead the normal tab is sent if you press CTRL-tab.

I say this is a mistake on the design of XFCE Terminal emulator, but theres no way I know to get rid of the kidnapping of tab!

Answer (score 0):

in my case 'set -u' was the culprit, I commented out in the .bash_profile, tab completion worked

Answer (score 0):

For who may be using Linux in docker, the tab auto complete may not work. I resovled it by create the link.

`ln -sf  /bin/bash /bin/sh`